# The conjugate function $\overline{f(z)}$ has derivative $0$ w.r.t $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

In ahlfors text it states that(formally)

> If the rules of calculus were applicable, we would obtain $$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}-i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\right), \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\right)$$

And we see that $f$ being analytic,

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = -i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$$ holds, which gives that,
$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=0$$

Now , in text following he states that,

the conjugate function $\overline{f(z)}$ has derivative $0$ w.r.t $z$.

That is ,
$$\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}}=0$$

I didn't get this.

Won't this mean , $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{x}}-i\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{y}}\right)$ , and from $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{x}} = -i\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{y}}$

I didn't see how it's coming, i suppose their a mistake of mine considering $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}} = \overline {\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}}$

Please explain,  where's the mistake , and what  does actually is the difference between differentiating a analytic function and its conjugate.

Comment: The conjugate function is not analytic, so by the chain rule it breaks analycity.

Comment: $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}} = \overline {({\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar z}}})}=0$ (just check definitions of the partials in $z, \bar z$ with $f=u+iv, \bar f=u-iv$)

Comment: @YvesDaoust , if it's not analytic,  then, what does applying chain rule means, sorry for my ignorance,  please explain a bit more.

Comment: @Conrad i understand the definition of partials in $z$ but please could you restate or provide a source,  about the same, thing in $\overline{z}$

Comment: with the motivation as noted above, we define $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\right)$; from here it is straightforward that $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}} = \overline {({\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar z}}})}$

Comment: @Conrad  thanks, i got it now

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate function is analytic as a function of $\overline{z}.$ So, letting $u =\overline{z},$ the computation you give implies that $\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{u}} = 0.$ But $\overline{u} = z,$ so what your professor says is true.

Comment: Thanks i understand,  and does the equations, $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{z}}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{x}}-i\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{y}}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{x}} = -i\frac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{y}}$ holds? Please explain a bit.